# What is the cause of redirection not working in react-router-dom 6.10.0?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I created my portfolio with `react-three-fiber` in SPA, but before deploying it on the internet I have to create a privacy policy page. To do this I add a footer in which there is a link supposed to display this page.
When I click on this link the url address becomes `"localhost:5173/pages/Privacy"` but I don’t have any page that appears.
I think I’ve tried everything, `Navigate`, `Link` `CreateBrowser` ... Someone to help me solve this problem?

The technologies I used were:

```json
"dependencies": {
    "@emailjs/browser": " 3.11.0",
    "@react-three/drei": "9.66.0",
    "@react-three/fiber": "8.12.2",
    "framer-motion": "10.12.7",
    "maath": " 0.5.3",
    "react": " 18.2.0",
    "react-dom": " 18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": " 6.10.0",
    "react-tilt": " 1.0.2",
    "react-vertical-timeline-component": " 3.6.0",
    "three": " 0.152.2"
  },
```

main.jsx:

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client'
import App from './App.jsx'
import './index.css'
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom'

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
    </BrowserRouter>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

App.jsx:

```
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import {
  About,
  Contact,
  Experience,
  Tech,
  Feedbacks,
  Hero,
  Navbar,
  Works,
  StarsCanvas,
  Footer,
} from "./components";
import Privacy from "../src/components/pages/Privacy";

// Structure de notre site
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="relative z-0 bg-primary">
      <div className="bg-hero-pattern bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center">
        <Navbar />
        <Hero />
      </div>

      <About />
      <Experience />
      <Tech />
      <Works />
      <Feedbacks />

      <div className="relative z-0">
        <Contact />
        <StarsCanvas />
      </div>

      <Footer />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="../src/components/pages/Privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

index.js:

```js
import { EarthCanvas, BallCanvas, ComputersCanvas, StarsCanvas } from './canvas';
import Hero from './Hero';
import Navbar from './Navbar';
import About from './About';
import Tech from './Tech';
import Experience from './Experience';
import Works from './Works';
import Feedbacks from './Feedbacks';
import Contact from './Contact';
import Footer from './Footer';
import Privacy from './pages/Privacy'

export {
  Hero,
  Navbar,
  About,
  Tech,
  Experience,
  Works,
  Feedbacks,
  Contact,
  EarthCanvas, 
  BallCanvas, 
  ComputersCanvas, 
  StarsCanvas,
  Footer, 
  Privacy
}
```

Footer.jsx:

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { styles } from "../styles";
import { logo } from "../assets";

const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <nav
      className={`${styles.paddingX} w-full flex items-center py-5 bg-primary`}
    >
      <div className="w-full flex justify-between items-center max-w-7xl mx-auto">
        <div className="flex items-center gap-2">
          <img src={logo} alt="logo" className="w-9 h-9 object-contain" />
          <p className="text-white/[0.6] text-[15px] font-bold cursor-pointer flex">
            Création Yann Cotard.
          </p>
        </div>
        <Link to="./pages/Privacy">
          <p className="text-white/[0.6] text-[15px] cursor-pointer flex">
            Politique de Confidentialité
          </p>
        </Link>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};

export default Footer;
```

I tried all the methods described in the `react-router` documentation and even asked chatgpt for help but without results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not rendering any route for `path="/pages/privacy"`, though you do have a route with a relative path `"../src/components/pages/Privacy"`. It seems you have confusion here what the `path` prop represents in a router. It's not a path to a file you want to render, but rather you are mapping a URL path to a React element you would like rendered.

The app/router is assumed to be rendered from root, e.g. `"/"`, so my suggestion would be to render a `"/privacy"` route.

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="relative z-0 bg-primary">
      <div className="bg-hero-pattern bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center">
        <Navbar />
        <Hero />
      </div>

      <About />
      <Experience />
      <Tech />
      <Works />
      <Feedbacks />

      <div className="relative z-0">
        <Contact />
        <StarsCanvas />
      </div>

      <Footer />
      <Routes>
        <Route path="/privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
      </Routes>
    </div>
  );
};
```

The `Footer` should obviously link to the correct path. Instead of a relative link target path, use an absolute path, e.g. `to="/privacy"`.

```
const Footer = () => {
  return (
    <nav ... >
      <div ... >
        ...
        <Link to="/privacy">
          ...
        </Link>
      </div>
    </nav>
  );
};
```

With the above `App` code however, all the normal content (*`Navbar`, `Hero`, `About`, ..., `Footer`*) is unconditionally rendered, and when the URL path is `"/privacy"` then the `Privacy` component will be rendered below the footer. If it's the case that you actually want the privacy page to be it's "own page" and above the footer, then you'll likely want to ***conditionally*** render the other content on *its* own page as well, save for common components like the nav and footer.

Example:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <div className="relative z-0 bg-primary">
      <div className="bg-hero-pattern bg-cover bg-no-repeat bg-center">
        <Navbar />
        <Hero />
      </div>

      <Routes>
        <Route
          path="/"
          element={(
            <>
              <About />
              <Experience />
              <Tech />
              <Works />
              <Feedbacks />

              <div className="relative z-0">
                <Contact />
                <StarsCanvas />
              </div>
            </>
          )}
        />
        <Route path="/privacy" element={<Privacy />} />
      </Routes>

      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
};
```